# Exit status convention in Unix programs

Tags: unix, return, posix, return-value, c11

Consider a Unix command `foo` that reads a file (or `stdin`) on a line-by-line basis where each line is expected to adhere to a specific format, for an example the `/etc/passwd` format.

If any of the lines are incorrect (but not all), should the termination status be `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`?

I have tried referring to the standard,

**[C11 Standard:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.20.4.3 The `exit` function**
**Para 5**

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of status is zero or
>   `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-deﬁned form of the status successful termination is
>   returned. If the value of status is `EXIT_FAILURE` , an implementation-deﬁned form
>   of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
>   implementation-deﬁned.

My interpretation of the above is that "implementation-defined" means that the decision is left to the implementer. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Some translations from C standard gibberish to English: implementation = compiler, implementation-defined = compiler-specific behavior (which in turn could depend on system-specific behavior). Everything in the C standard is written in such a way that it addresses the person writing the compiler, rather than the end user/application programmer.

Comment: Evidently: Reference from Jimbo's Emporium of Various Stuff (i.e. Wikipedia): [Exit Status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "implementation defined" in the C standard means the platform implementation, and *not* the programmer of an individual application.

What this sentence means is that different platforms can have different conventions on how success or failure is transmitted to the environment, e.g to a shell. Implementations may also provide means to distinguish different codes for failure, depending on the reasons that lead to it. But then such codes may not be portable between different systems.

For the semantics of what you as a programmer consider to be success or failure, you are completely free to do whatever is appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You’re correct that the decision is left up to the implementer. It depends on how the program is to be used.

For example, if `foo` terminates with a failure when it encounters incorrectly formatted input, a user of `foo` could write a shell script that checks its exit status and alerts her with an email containing the contents of `stderr`. If `foo` terminates successfully, there would be no need for an email to be sent.